# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inspectedWindow' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to build a chrome-extension, but when I run this

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources(function(response){
        console.log("enter");
    });
});
```

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'inspectedWindow' of undefined.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Go to the console and check if chrome.devtools is available. You may not have added the devtools page in your manifest file. ` "devtools_page": "devtools.html",` with devtools.html being your page. See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools for more info

Answer (score 4):

This API is only available in the context of a DevTools page:

[image: DevTools extension]

As noted, you need to add a page to DevTools via manifest:

```
"devtools_page": "devtools.html"
```

Then this page will be loaded (and its scripts executed) each time that DevTools is opened.

> An instance of the extension's DevTools page is created each time a DevTools window opens. The DevTools page exists for the lifetime of the DevTools window. The DevTools page has access to the DevTools APIs and a limited set of extension APIs.

See [the docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) for more details.

---

If you need the same information as the DevTools API provides, but without opening DevTools, you can take a look at the [`debugger` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger). Be warned, it's a heavy hammer. *Or rather, a heavy but delicate device that shouldn't be used as a simple hammer..*

Otherwise, to interact with the page's content you may need to inject a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) or snoop on traffic with [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest).